# Pre-Compiled Templates in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix docs say that *"The fact that Phoenix templates are pre-compiled makes them extremely fast."*.

I have a few questions,  what does pre-compiling templates actually mean and how much of a significant difference will this make in production, compared to something like a Rails App.

Answer (score 6):

> what does pre-compiling templates actually mean

pre-compiling here means that all the templates in `web/templates` are actually compiled into normal function clauses of the `render` function in the corresponding `View`.

If you have a `PostView` and a template in `web/templates/posts/index.html.eex` with the contents:

```
<pre><%= inspect(@posts) %></pre>
```

then having that file is almost* exactly the same as adding the following function to `PostView`:

```
def render("index.html", assigns) do
  "<pre>" <> inspect(assigns[:posts]) <> "</pre>"
end
```

*almost because Phoenix handles auto HTML escaping before injecting strings (to prevent XSS), returns iolists instead of concatenating binaries (for performance), and more.

[Here's](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/template.ex) the implementation of this compilation logic in Phoenix. (Search for "before_compile" and "defp compile" on the page.)

> how much of a significant difference will this make in production, compared to something like a Rails App

I'm sure Rails also must have a template caching mechanism, at least for production, and probably for development too. I'm not familiar much with the speed/implementation of Rails' templates to comment on this.